# css3 arrow with drop shadow

Tags: html, css

Hey currently I have this css to produce a css arrow but I cannot seem to get a drop shadow on it any ideas

```
.arrow {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid inset;
    border-width: 10px 78px 0 78px;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I have dabbled with :after and :before but with no success

Comment: Last month for my own work I spent hours and hours working on this and there's diddly squat. I needed it for a testimonial box, instead I did this: http://jsbin.com/OjexExa/1/edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your arrow is going to be placed under a solid rectangle, this can help you

```
.demo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    clip: rect(0px 400px 100px 0px);    
}
.demo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-90px, -45px) skew(80deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(-90px, -45px) skew(80deg) rotate(-5deg);
    transform: translate(-90px, -45px) skew(80deg) rotate(-5deg);
    box-shadow: 30px 1px 6px blue;
}
```

[fiddle compared with your original arrow](http://jsfiddle.net/LXtzX/)

The problem is that the shadow can not go upwards, but usually this design wouldn't need that anyway.

Also, the base div is highly distorted, so you will need to set the shadow by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

I think that's what you're looking for, it explains two methods to get a shadow on arrows with CSS.

One is to use a unicode triangle character and apply a shadow to that, the other is using CSS trickery with the :after selector and CSS transform.

Comment: The problem with this is I need a triangle of 156px wide and only 10px high. The one you linked me only allows for an equilateral triangle